# How to block call flow with async await

Tags: c#

I am tasked with freeing the UI of a large poorly written WPF application. I'm doing this by identifying long running tasks and making them async. However, due to the maze of daisy chained method calls, this is proving difficult. The problem is that I need to block code execution at any given point simply to allow the UI to be free mainly for busy indicator responsiveness.

The problem is that using async await allows the execution to fall back to the caller and allows the code to continuing executing which often is dependent on the results of the code I'm making async. The simple solution is to scope out the async wrapping so that it's wrapping all code, but this is much easier said than done with such a mess of code.

Consider the following code:

```
private string someField = string.Empty;

private void Start()
{
    this.DoSomething();
    this.UseString();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    this.DoSomethingAsync();
}

private async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        someField = LongRunningMethodThatManipulatesString();
    });
}

private void UseString()
{
    //do something with someField
}
```

The UseString() method is attempting to use the variable someField though it's value may or may not be set yet depending on the status of the code within the Task.Run method.

Is there a solution to this problem or is this just a string I'll need to keep unraveling?

Comment: _"How to block call flow with async await"_ - that sounds like "How to make something sticky with WD40" ...

Comment: `async void` is a bug. Such methods can't be awaited. Change the signature to `async Task` and make sure you await the method. That means that all methods should become `async Task` all the way to the top

Comment: This means: `private async Task StartAsync() { await DoSomethingAsync(); UseString(); }` with `private Task DoSomethingAsync() { return Task.Run(...); }`. And the call of Start() would have to be awaited too.

Comment: ^^ And furthermore leads to the necessity to make the caller async (Task), too. And the caller of the caller ... and so on up the chain. => Expect to have to basically dissect your app and render it "temporarily broken" for quite some time.

Comment: `async void` should only be used at the top level of an `await` from an event handler. Otehrwise use a normal `async Task` and `await` it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposed example should be rewritten as:

```
private async Task Start()
{
    var str = await this.DoSomethingAsync();
    this.UseString(str);
}

private Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(LongRunningMethodThatManipulatesString);
}

private void UseString(string someField)
{
    //do something with someField
}
```

This way the data flow between methods is explicit and easy understand. Having various methods reading and writing shared data from multiple threads will be very difficult to do safely.

In some cases it can be useful to store the task for some operation, something like:

```
Task<string> someField ;
bool isRunning;
public void Start(){
    someField = DoSomethingAsync();
    isRunning= true;
}
public void End(){
    UseString(await someField );
    isRunning = false;
}
```

In general when dealing with multi threaded or async code:

- Try to make methods pure and types immutable whenever possible. This makes state management and thread safety easier.
- only use `async void` in the outer layer, i.e. button event handlers
- Tasks should be awaited (or at least handled somehow)
- Consider if you need to handle exceptions, for example OperationCancelledException.
- Whenever `Task.Run` or equivalent is used you need to make sure the called code is thread safe, and this can be a fairly tough to guarantee if thread safety was not originally considered.

To block the UI thread while doing some background work you can use some type of modal progress bar to block input, while still providing feedback to the user and keeping the UI responsive. This might look something like:

```
var progress = new MyProgressDialog();
var task = Task.Run(MySlowMethod);
task.ContinueWith(t => progress.Close(), TaskScheduler.Current);
progress.ShowDialog(); 
var result = task.Result; // task should always be completed by now
```

This should run the work on a background thread, show a modal dialog, and close the dialog when the work is completed. You might also want to add some way to report [progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-8.0) and to [cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-8.0) the slow work. This is *fairly* safe, since it reduces the risk of the UI thread and worker thread accessing the same data concurrently. But the UI thread will still process messages, so you need to pay some attention to thread safety.

Comment: + be aware of swallowed Exceptions. For example when using `await Task.WhenAll( coupleOfTasks )` ..

Comment: This is a great answer and I agree with the proposed code. However, like I said in my question, my sample code was an oversimplified version of the problems I'm facing. What I'm left with is detangling a mess of code so that it's in a better form and to be able to achieve this form. That's ok, but I was hoping that someone may have come up with a solution to these types of problems even if they are a bit hacky. The code I'm working with is being deprecated in the next couple of years and I'm looking for a stopgap solution to pacify current customers for this company. Thanks!

Comment: @flyNflip I understand the example is oversimplified, it is just difficult to provide more specific recommendations since legacy code typically have a huge number of things to consider. In some cases a modal progress dialog might be appropriate. That will in essence stop the UI thread at a specific point, while still providing feedback to the user, and optionally allow cancelling of the background work.

Comment: The modal indicator is the ultimate goal. However, since almost all code was originally written on the main thread, if I spin an indicator, it stops execution of any code. Conversely, if I run the code, the indicator cannot spin. I was hoping for a generalized suggestion or pattern to solve the problem in my sample code. It sounds like that doesn't exist. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @flyNflip Added an example that should show how to trap the UI thread while doing work in the background.

Comment: Your example is exactly my approach which has been painful. I'm constantly having to fight code that isn't thread safe such as ObservableCollections and trying to find ways to shove that code back on the UI thread. I wish I could show an example, but that would be difficult because we are often talking about thousands of lines of code in a single call stack. I'm getting there slowly, but it is a horrible experience. It sure would be nice if there was a simple way to run an indicator graphic from a second UI thread. Gaining perceived speed from a busy indicator would be a massive win.

Comment: @flyNflip I feel your pain. If the code has a poor structure it will be painful, I do not think there is any way around that. If you have not already done so you might want to take a look at [What are the key points of Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122014/what-are-the-key-points-of-working-effectively-with-legacy-code), it might help a little bit.